# Активность discord на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css, discord, activity

не давно наткнулся на показ активности дискорда на сайте, и загорелся желанием сделать похожее, мои навыки JS не достаточны дабы соорудить что-то такое, обращаюсь к Вам за помощь. Знаю лишь что реализовуется через бота, и участника на сервере, он должен получать активность через `activities.read`

Буду благодарен за помощь!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Было бы неплохо привести пример данных активности, думаю так будет легче для всех.